# iOS app need to design a flexible and elegant way to pop surprise gift messages to users in different places within my app

Tags: ios, design-patterns, state, viewcontroller

I am building an iOS app with the following view controllers:

1) ProductViewController - displays a carousel of products. When the user rotates to a product, the user can pick a button to see details of the product in view or another button to add the product to a shopping cart

2) HistoryViewController - displays detailed history about the products on a vertically scrolling timeline (Implemented using UIScrollView).

3) GameViewController - initiates a game where the user can play a trivia game where he scrolls through a set of views using back and forth arrow buttons (there are about 20 of these)

OK so much for the setup... here is the crux of my design problem:
I want to create popup messages for the user when the user gets to certain key points in the app. Lets call these key points "anchor points"

So for example the popup appears as soon as the user sees the 3rd product in the carousel view (i.e. in ProductViewController)

The popup appears again when the user gets halfway down the HistoryView (in HistoryViewController)

The popup appears again when the user gets to sees 7 items in GameViewController.

I want to add these "anchor points" in a flexible manner so I can easily change those places in the app where the popup appears (with minimal code change and mainly through config)

Q1) What would be the best way or design pattern to use to go about this design?

Q2) As a later enhancement I want to use some of the anchor points as key anchor points where if a user has gone through a certain number of key anchor points I can send the user a special message.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably think about having a separate controller (maybe a singleton) to own the knowledge for this. It deals with any configuration and the number of triggers required before any message is shown.

The other controllers in the app shouldn't know about counts or what things are being monitored for, so notifications are a good option. Define a set of notifications (for the types of events which go into making your anchor points) and have all of your controllers post the notifications as events happen.

Your separate controller deals with observing the notifications, counting and displaying the messages. If the display is as alerts or modal display it's easy. If not, the controller should have a link to the root view controller so it can get the current top controller (alert or modal is preferable).

Comment: Thanks Wain, this appears very elegant. I agree with alert or modal - that is how I need to do the display of the popups. I have one question- can you give me a little more detail on how to implement that singleton Controller? Is that a UIViewController or just a Model object. I may not be understanding this right but is it a UIViewController which is never pushed into view...? Can you point me to any samples of how to implement that?

Comment: It would be a subclass of `NSObject`. It has no view itself. Search for how to create a singleton in Obj-C and you'll find may options (dispatch once is best).

Comment: Yes sure I know how to create a singleton but the question is if it is a NSObject how can I get it to display or trigger the display of the alert-view? Is that done via another NSNotification?

Comment: `UIAlertView` is just shown, it's all handled for you. The controller just acts as the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer, hopefully I understood the question correctly and this helps.

Create a popup manager class and initiate where ever it needs to be created first(app delegate?) to keep track of the user progression, and have the popup manager class pop alert messages to let user know of the surprise you have for them.